# How to Build a List of Form Controls Before the Form is Loaded

Tags: vb.net, list

I’m new to OOP and VB.NET, so please bear with me.

In VB.Net I currently have working code that defines, for each form, significant information about selected controls on the form.

I have defined in a public class:

```
Public Class FormFld
    Public Property ScrField As Control ' A control on the form
    Public Property DbField As String   ' Its corresponding field name in the database
    …                                   ' Other info about the control or its database field
End Class
```

When each form loads, I create a list of FormFlds for the form’s selected controls:
At the start of each form

```
ReadOnly FormFlds As New List(Of FormFld)()
```

and in the form’s Load routine

```
FormFlds.Add(New FormFld With {.ScrField = Control1Name, .DbField = "Field1Name", …})
FormFlds.Add(New FormFld With {.ScrField = Control2Name, .DbField = "Field2Name", …})
…
```

This technique has worked well to easily loop through the selected fields and, on input, populate those fields from the database, or, on output, write those field values to the database.

With this implementation, however, the list must be built every single time the form is loaded. I’m wondering if the setup of the list can be done only once, during program initialization, before the forms are loaded.

Here’s the latest that I have tried.
In Class1:

```
Public Class indiv
    Public FormFlds As List(Of FormFld)() ' The list for the frmIndividual form
End Class
```

In Module1, I attempt defining the FormFlds for the eventual form frmIndividual, to be saved as Indiv.FormFlds. I’d like the form name (f) and the list owner (owner) to be defineable so I can easily change those for each form.

```
Dim owner As New indiv
Dim f As FrmIndividual
owner.FormFlds.Add(New FormFld With {.ScrField = f.TxtKey, .DbField = "Sort_Key", …})
```

In Visual Studio, the third line shows error “BC30456: 'Add' is not a member of 'List(Of FormFld)()”.

Wondering if the problem might be due to not having an actual form FrmIndividual created yet, I tried changing the second line to

```
Dim f As New FrmIndividual
```

but it didn’t change anything.

I’m using VS 2022, v17.2.1. If there’s more info you need, please let me know.

Comment: You could move ReadOnly FormFlds As New List(Of FormFld)() further up the call stack, say in your main sub or using ApplicationEvents, could still load it on the First time the form loads as per your doing now (eg. If FormFlds.Count < 1 Then... etc) Will save you loading stuff for forms that might not get called etc

Comment: If the form doesn't exist then the controls don't exist, so how could you put them in a list? If you create multiple instances of a form type then each instance contains different control objects, so if you expect to refer to those objects then you must build that list separately for each form instance.

Comment: @Hursey: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The code I’m developing is run at the very start of program execution. However, your suggestion is reasonable, and I may implement it, subject to the question of whether the values stored during the first load of the form are valid for later loads. See my response below to John’s comment.

Comment: @John: I thank you for taking the time to respond. Your question may be reasonable, and in fact, just before posting my original query I removed a line where I mentioned that this whole process may not be viable with different instances of the same form. However… as I said at the end of my original post, I am creating a new occurrence via 
        Dim f As New FrmIndividual
just before the .Add for the list.

Comment: @John: As a side note: In my 50 years employed by a major software development company as an assembly language programmer and compiler developer, I have found that typically an object’s properties are internally kept as address offsets from the start of the object. Once the object is loaded, a reference to one of its properties causes the addition of the object address and the property’s offset. I don’t know how VB.Net handles this internally, but if it does indeed act this way, ...

Comment: @John: ...then it’s possible that even when the form is -not- yet loaded, the references kept in the list might be offsets, and therefore viable later on when the form -is- loaded. The code I’m developing will help me prove whether or not my idea ultimately will work.

Comment: Finally, a comment that applies to both responses received. The question I posted gave a lot of background to help responders answer my sole question: Why does my code get error “BC30456: 'Add' is not a member of 'List(Of FormFld)()”? Or put another way, what do I have to change to make the .Add work?

Comment: @Rizz Kid Re your finial comment, this is just my gut on this one I admit but would think this goes back to  Johns first question, it's simply at that stage the form controls don't exist.  I would look at moving your Control creation to the form constructor rather than Load event.  Side topic, Code Modules in this context might sound like a good idea, but I really think you will find it more maintainable to keep everything in one spot.  At least look at using Inheritance rather than jumping out to separate modules

Comment: @John: Thank you both for your kind and valid responses. I’m trying lots of variations on my plan in order to understand OOP better. John: Your answer was spot on, and fixed the error I had. I will close the document shortly and flag your response as the answer. But I’d like to sneak in one more question though, while I have this all documented.

You suggested I move the code to the constructor, and I will do that. These are Windows forms. Is the constructor in <formname>.Designer.vb? If not, then where do I find it?

Comment: And as Hursey suggested, I will check FormFlds.Count so the setup code only runs once. That requires that FormFlds be defined somewhere more global than the form itself. My plan (see my original post) was to create a global object for each form, e.g., Indiv for frmIndividual, and that object would contain FormFlds. In the form itself I would reference Indiv.FormFlds . Is the code I originally showed (Public Class Indiv, Public FormFlds) the proper way to design it?

Comment: Add your own constructor to the user code file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're told there's no `Add` method is because arrays have no `Add` method and you have an array. Here:

```vb
ReadOnly FormFlds As New List(Of FormFld)()
```

You are using the `New` keyword to invoke a constructor, so the parentheses at the end are for the argument list for that method call. Here:

```vb
Public FormFlds As List(Of FormFld)()
```

there's no `New` keyword so there's no constructor, so the parentheses at the end indicate that the field is an array type. That code is functionally equivalent to this:

```vb
Public FormFlds() As List(Of FormFld)
```

When you get that field you're getting a reference to an array of List(Of FormFld), not just a single List(Of FormFld) object. Of course, the field is initially `Nothing` anyway, so you'd have to assign something to it first to be able to use it.

By the way, the error message was already telling you what the issue was:

'Add' is not a member of 'List(Of FormFld)**()**`

It is telling you that `Add` is not a member of `array of List(Of FormFld)`, which it's obviously not.